# Disk space analyzer for Linux/Ubuntu with extra cool features

Tags: linux, gui, ubuntu

I know that  quite a few not bad disk space analyzers for Linux/Ubuntu already exist. However, I've kinda "fallen in love" with [SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/features.html) on Windows. Thus I'm interested if there's a tool which would have "that extra polish" on Linux/Ubuntu. A quick intro screenshot to give a general idea about how every tool like this that I've seen usually looks like, more or less:

[image: SpaceSniffer screenshot]

Ok, so that was the fluff, now let's get rough and coldly spec out my fancies:

- **<kbd>Must</kbd>** work **on Ubuntu**. Support for other Linux distros will be *"looked upon well"*. More supported OSes/platforms are cool, but not required here.
- **<kbd>Must</kbd>** be at least **gratis** (freeware). Strong preference for  libre or at least open-source, but closed source is grudgingly acceptable for me here, as long as I don't pay. But ***must not*** send any data over the network; please, no spyware, I can't even imagine how network could be any value here.
- **<kbd>Strongly prefer</kbd>** a **GUI app**. TUI (i.e. curses-based/...) are not excluded, but I don't believe they would do it for me. Quickly hovering over stuff with a mouse and exploring by clicking is super powerful here. Purely CLI batch-mode stuff (e.g. `df`) is not  accepted; must be interactive.
- **<kbd>Must</kbd>** show disk usage by directories/files as **"squares/rectangles"**, also show the name and actual size per directory/file at least when hovering the mouse over the rectangle, and must easily allow retrieving the whole path to the dir/file. [This is mostly a generic/baseline requirement for this kind of a tool.]
- **<kbd>Must</kbd>** allow some reasonable **drill-down**.
- **<kbd>Must</kbd>** be able to choose at least the initial **mount point ("disk") to scan**. Ideally, it'd show a list of mount points to choose from, but also allow specifying any custom path to a directory.
- <kbd>Should</kbd> be able to work in *sudo mode* and in *non-sudo mode*. <kbd>Should</kbd> display some *info whether* it is in sudo mode or in limited non-root mode.
- <kbd>Should</kbd> handle *inaccessible paths* in some reasonable way. At least not crash/hang on them. Ideally, show them as "inaccessible space" on the graph (size could probably be deduced by subtracting `total space - free space = inaccessible space`).

Now, the "extra features" I like in SpaceSniffer, which I'd like to see in a Linux tool; please note it ***MUST*** have ***at least one*** of those; otherwise I'm no better than with what I already use:

- <kbd>Should</kbd> start drawing the rectangles immediately after starting, and **update the graph "live" as it is scanning** the disk for the first time. (Most of the tools I've seen show "loading", and draw the grid only after they finished scanning.)
- <kbd>Should</kbd> be able to **display a rectangle for "free space" and for "unscanned (yet) space"**. This second feature (unscanned space) works especially well in a combo with the previous ("live/early drawing") feature.
- <kbd>Should</kbd> **dynamically update** the graph when **files on disk are changing** (i.e. use a feature like "inotify"). For example, if I delete a file on disk, I should see the graph update rather quickly afterwards to show the new situation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "what I already use" — What do you already use?